# Openpyxl returns wrong hyperlink address after delete_rows()

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

**Problem:** I have a program that scrapes Twitter and returns the results in an excel file. Part of each entry is a column containing a hyperlink to the Tweet and image included in the Tweet if applicable. Entries and hyperlinks work fine except when I run the following code to remove duplicate posts:

```
    #Remove duplicate posts.
    values = []
    i = 2
    while i <= sheet.max_row:
        if sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value in values:
            sheet.delete_rows(i,1)
        else:
            values.append(sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value)
            i+=1
```

After running the duplicate removal snippet the hyperlinks point to what I assume is the offset of deleted entries. Here is the code for creating a Twitter entry:

```
sheet.cell(row=row, column=8).hyperlink = "https://twitter.com/"+str(tweet.user.screen_name)+"/status/"+str(tweet.id)
sheet.cell(row=row, column=8).style = "Hyperlink"
```

**Expected Results:** Should be able to remove duplicate entries and keep the hyperlink pointed to the correct address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyperlinks point to the correct addresses for whatever reason when I change the code to the this:

```
sheet.cell(row=row, column=8).value = "https://twitter.com/"+str(tweet.user.screen_name)+"/status/"+str(tweet.id)
sheet.cell(row=row, column=8).style = "Hyperlink"
```

Requires a rapid double click to work as a hyperlink in the excel sheet versus the one click when inserting using .hyperlink.

So fixed but not fixed.